# elif function error in code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am brand new to Python and am trying to build a text based game.
The first question is "How old are you?"

How can I use if/else statements to print a certain message when the user doesn't input his age.

for instance if the user inputs a character instead of a letter I want to print "please enter a digit, not characters" or if the user inputs a digit smaller than 12 I want to print "You are not old enough" and if the user inputs a digit greater or equal to 12 I want to say "Welcome"

I have written some code to try and do this myself and spent about 4 hours on it but can't figure it out.

This is my block of code:

```
 input_age = raw_input("What is your age, " + input_name + "? ")
 if len(input_age) == 0:
   print("You didn't enter anything")
 elif input_age < 12 and input_age.isdigit():
   print("Sorry, you are not old enogh to play")
 elif input_age >= 12 and input_age.isdigit():
   print ("Welcome")
 else:
   print("You entered a character or characters instead of a digit or digits")
```

For some reason the elif on line 4 gets skipped or something because even if i enter 4 as my age it still carries on and prints "Welcome" instead of "You are not old enough"

Comment: Your unindented Python code is not a [mcve]. The indentation matters.

Comment: When I try to execute your program then I get "IndentationError: expected an indented block" and it does not run at all. so please check if you have introduced some errors when pasting your program into this  post

Comment: Comparing a string to an int doesn't give the same results as comparing an int to an int. If you want to tell if your input is less than 12, cast it to an int first.

Comment: `raw_input()` always returns a string.

Comment: Thanks Khelwood, makes sense.  How would i use int() to cast it to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@roganjosh is right, `raw_input` returns a string, so you have to do the below:

```
input_age = raw_input("What is your age, " + input_name + "? ")
if not input_age:
  print("You didn't enter anything")
elif input_age.isdigit():
   if int(input_age) < 12 :
       print("Sorry, you are not old enogh to play")
   elif int(input_age) >= 12:
     print ("Welcome")
if not input_age.isdigit():
  print("You entered a character or characters instead of a digit or digits")
```